# How can i get the object that was null as (shown in the picture)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, nullreferenceexception, asp.net-core-middleware

[Exception Description with annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9XyS.png)
I am creating a middleware exception handler for an ASP.NET Core project and I am trying to get the source of the exception (as in the object that caused it). I can see the object when I am using the debugger, but i can't get it programmatically.

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> _logger;


    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500 if unexpected


        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Error = ex.Message, Soure = ex.Source });
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
```

I expected the source property in the exception to contain it, but it just shows the class.

Comment: Here are two articles on Exception handling that I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET To get to the original causer, you had to recurse over the inner exceptions. But usually it is way simpler to just get Exception.ToString() and log or expose that.

Comment: @Christopher thank for your help but I have just tried that unfortunately it didn't include the info i needed.   if u check the picture u will find the entity that caused the null reference explicitly mentioned

Comment: This execption means. "Dude, there is no object behind lookup! I can not access a Instance Function or field if you do not give me a instance to work with". Considering you are getting the value for lookup by doing a string comparision on a list of mail adresse, you **really** have to expect nothing to be found.

Comment: Yeah i get that i need it to spit out "Lookup" that is what i am trying to do. To be more precises i am trying to access it from from the exception object.

Comment: why not just use the safe navigation operator and prevent the exception from happening in the first place? There's no mystery here. The exception is from trying to access `lookup`'s properties when `lookup` is null.

Comment: I did that to cause the exception intentionally to test the handler i want to create a handler that is able to detect the source property of the exception, I want it to spit out that lookup was empty exactly like the picture

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge, there is only one way to do what you want:
Write a try...catch block for each and every property. This is simply not feasible.

Lookup is actually not even the soruce of this exception. It comes from somewhere in the function resolution mechanic. I am honestly not sure wich code precisely is throwing it, but I know the variable lookup did it's job (correctly taking, storing and returning "null") and is in no way at fault for this.

null values are right up there with [Boneheaded Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/). As in it is literally mentioned. Go and prevent it from ever happening: "Boneheaded exceptions are your own darn fault, you could have prevented them and therefore they are bugs in your code. You should not catch them; doing so is hiding a bug in your code. Rather, you should write your code so that the exception cannot possibly happen in the first place, and therefore does not need to be caught. **That argument is null**, that typecast is bad, that index is out of range, you're trying to divide by zero – these are all problems that you could have prevented very easily in the first place, so prevent the mess in the first place rather than trying to clean it up."

Honestly, I can not really make sense of this function. Are you trying to put a Admin user into the DB? If so what does "AdminResponse" mean in this context?

Comment: My target was to create a handler which can spit out the property as shown in the picture , I caused the exception intentionally to test it , It was able to return the Class where the exception happened i want ed to go a bit further and spit out the property that was causing the error from the handler as the arrow denotes in the picture

Comment: in the picture the exception had and explicit line saying that property "lookup" is null i want to create a handler that finds out (in any scenario) which property i tried to access and found null

Comment: @Hackavist in general, I don't think this is going to be possible in production code without, as Christopher is pointing out, a lot of work. You are able to get that while debugging because of all the extra work and meta data the debugger is using. That information isn't tracked outside the debugger.

Comment: @Hackavist: The thing is - the Property or Field is in no way, shape or form at fault for this. It did it's job. It took a value. It stored it. It handed it back. Unlike Darth Vader when defending the 1st Death Star, **it did it's job**. The function whose name you have now hidden is who is responsible for this mess.

Comment: I get your point now @Christopher, i will try fix all the manageable errors as you mentioned earlier and to follow the exception handling guide lines, Thank you for your Time and Effort

Comment: With Roslyn, you might be able to do some work that would inject stuff into the exception handling that would include the name of the variable for things like this at compile time so you wouldn't literally have to manually insert try/catch around every attempt to access a variable(make the compiler do it for you), but even if you could get it to work, it seems that means overriding the work of the .net compilers team and would probably result in a very inefficient implementation.

Comment: "I want to create a handler that finds out which property i tried to access", my guy you screenshot shows you are already doing this. You didn't get this exception from accessing a property inside lookup. You got this exception from lookup itself. It doesn't matter which property you are trying to access if the object containing those properties is null itself. `null` has no properties, so how can you select a property of null to blame? The properties aren't the problem, its the null object itself.

Comment: Any property you try to access on `null` will throw this exception. You could think of all the properties of a null object as null, but in truth it has no properties. It doesn't make sense to try to isolate a property of `null` when no properties exist on it